# C# Linq GroupBy, get list of a column in each group

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to write a query to get all the shipping costs of sales, and compare it against an estimated shipping cost.  Here is my query:

```
var sales = (from sale in db.Sales
             where sale.DateOfSale > startDate && sale.DateOfSale < endDate
             group sale by new {sale.ItemID, sale.EstimatedShipping} into g
             select new
             {
                 ItemID = g.Key.ItemID
                 Estimate = g.Key.EstimatedShipping
                 ActualShipCosts = (from gSales in g select gSales.ActualShipping)
             }).ToList();
```

It seems that doing anything with the group that isn't getting the group by keys or doing g.Count() makes the query run terribly slow, I can't get this query to finish without timing out.  Is there anything I can do to help performance here?

Comment: What are you doing with the result set? Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: What estimated number of records query returns before grouping? Do you need ActualShipCosts as list?

Comment: Before grouping I am getting around 50k results depending on the dates.  I can skip the group by and filter later (takes ~10 sec) but I was hoping to figure out a faster option.  I would like the ActualShipCosts as a list but adding a .ToList() to the ActualShipCosts query seemed to make it an invalid query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try performing the *ActualShipping* selection while you are building the result set:

```
var sales = db.Sales
    .Where(sale => sale.DateOfSale > startDate && sale.DateOfSale < endDate)
    .GroupBy(
        sale => new {sale.ItemID, sale.EstimatedShipping},
        sale => sale.ActualShipping)
    .ToList();
```

Not sure, but it could prevent additional enumeration.

Comment: I think I want a .Select( g => new {g.Key, ShipCosts = g.ToList()}) between the .GroupBy() and the .ToList()... but I am getting the same error as before, Linq to Entities does not recognize the method....

Comment: Turns out looping through those results and listing the .ActualShipping takes practically no time...thank you, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

I think problem can be caused by `(from gSales in g select gSales.ActualShipping)`. Linq `group by` is translated into `group by` in SQL, so you don't have direct access to records which forms group. Each call of `(from gSales in g select gSales.ActualShipping)` will do separate select.

First possible solution: create index on ItemID, EstimatedShipping pair.

Second possible solution:

```
var sales = (from sale in db.Sales
         where sale.DateOfSale > startDate && sale.DateOfSale < endDate
         select new
         {
             ItemID = sale.ItemID
             Estimate = sale.EstimatedShipping
             ActualShipCosts = sale.ActualShipping
         }).ToList();

var groupedSales = (from sale in sales
         group sale by new {sale.ItemID, sale.EstimatedShipping} into g
         select new
         {
             ItemID = g.Key.ItemID,
             Estimate = g.Key.EstimatedShipping,
             ActualShipCosts = g.Select(gSales => gSales.ActualShipping).ToList()
         }).ToList();
```

This will do grouping offline, after records are downloaded. It will for sure reduce number of queries, but you must check on your db to see if it's quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell without all the database for test, but this line could be the problem :

```
(from gSales in g select gSales.ActualShipping)
```

Try this instead:

```
var sales = (from sale in db.Sales
             where sale.DateOfSale > startDate && sale.DateOfSale < endDate
             group sale by new {sale.ItemID, sale.EstimatedShipping} into g
             select new
             {
                 ItemID = g.Key.ItemID,
                 Estimate = g.Key.EstimatedShipping,
                 ActualShipCosts = g.Select(gSales => gSales.ActualShipping).ToList()
             }).ToList();
```

This prevent a second `from`. The first query might doing some weird joins, whereas with a simple Select it should not.